# React + Redux + Router > Async Serverside Rendering > Components that are not directly linked with route doesn't receive staticContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, server-side-rendering

I am trying to implement Serverside rendering with React, Redux and Router.

Problem is I am not able to access `staticContext` in the components which are not linked with route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use `withRouter` from `react-router` and `staticContext` along with other routing params like `match` , `history`  and `location` were passed to the container

[Reference](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)